# Where was Sally at the beginning of The Hours?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hours

I've watched "The Hours," many times. I just noticed (oddly) that Sally in the beginning title sequence of the movie comes home in the small hours of the morning to lie down in bed with Clarissa.

Was this meant to imply there was an affair? There doesn't seem to be any literature on the reason she came in late-morning in the introduction.

Comment: I've consulted the book to reveal the answer, but there is nothing; so I am wondering if there has been discussion about this opening sequence in the movie from the director or screen writer.

Answer (score 2):

Sally was out at work and didn't want to disturb her long-term partner, who she knows is a relatively light sleeper. Later in [the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-hours-2002.pdf) we get this exchange, talking about the party.

> [SALLY has put the bags down in the kitchen, and is beginning to get oranges out of them.]
>
> **SALLY:** ***I got somebody to cover for me at work. I'll be with you all night.***

In [the source novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11899.The_Hours) she's described as the producer of an artsy-fartsy '*interview show*', the sort that goes out very late at night.

> Sally met Oliver St. Ives when he appeared on the very serious, very
> highbrow interview show she co-produces (which would never, of course,
> have considered him when he was just an action hero, and not one of
> the first rank)
>
> <sub><sup>[*The Hours*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11899.The_Hours) by Michael Cunningham</sup></sub>